# DB2 Toad Visualize Table Relationships

Tags: sql, db2

I have been scouring the internet for days trying to find relevant relationship visualizations using Toad for DB2 to see relevant table keys/ linkages for my JOIN statements.  Everything I have been able to find has been less than helpful.  My Current method is to run on the two tables that have information I want to join...

SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY

SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY

Then visually look for markers that look the same.  Needless to say this is taking forever and extremely inefficient.  I am trying to see what feature should I use to quickly see from table to table if there are relevant keys to join information.  Help me Obi Wan, your my only hope!

Answer (score 0):

If your database has foreign keys defined, and if you are using Db2 for LUW you would find foreign keys in the table SYSCAT.REFERENCES

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001057.html

If there are no Foreign Keys, and the person who designed the database has gone AWOL and left no documentation, then there are tools available that will attempt to discover table relationships from the data contents. An example of such a tool is https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/infosphere-information-analyzer